# BindException: Address already in use

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying my hands on socket programming in Java. To get things roll, I tried a very simple server and client code snippet as below

```
public class Server {

    //initialize socket and input stream
    private Socket socket = null;
    private ServerSocket server = null;
    private DataInputStream in = null;

    public Server(int port) {
        // starts server and waits for a connection
        while (true) {
            try{
                server = new ServerSocket(port);
                System.out.println("Server started");
                System.out.println("Waiting for a client ...");
                socket = server.accept();
                System.out.println("Client accepted");
                // takes input from the client socket
                in = new DataInputStream(
                        new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                // reads message from client until "Over" is sent
                while (!line.equals("Over"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        line = in.readUTF();
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    catch(IOException i)
                    {
                        System.out.println(i);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Closing connection");
                // close connection
                socket.shutdownInput();
                socket.shutdownOutput();
                socket.close();
                in.close();
            }
            catch(IOException i){
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Server(5000);
    }
}
```

Client.java looks like below

```
public class Client {

    // initialize socket and input output streams
    private Socket socket = null;
    private DataInputStream input = null;
    private DataOutputStream out = null;
    // constructor to put ip address and port
    public Client(String address, int port)
    {
        // establish a connection
        try
        {
            socket = new Socket(address, port);
            System.out.println("Connected");
            // takes input from terminal
            input = new DataInputStream(System.in);
            // sends output to the socket
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException u)
        {
            System.out.println(u);
        }
        catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }// string to read message from input
        String line = "";
        // keep reading until "Over" is input
        while (!line.equals("Over"))
        {
            try
            {
                line = input.readLine();
                out.writeUTF(line);
            }
            catch(IOException i)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
        // close the connection
        try
        {
            input.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Client client = new Client("127.0.0.1", 5000);
    }
}
```

It works fine for the first connection with the client. As soon as the client sends **Over** server starts giving exception `java.net.BindException: Address already in use`.

Even if I am closing the socket, why the port is in use?

Comment: Which ports are you using for server/client ?

Comment: @ToTheMax it is in the main method. 5000.

Comment: Mentioned in main method: 5000

Comment: Remove `server = new ServerSocket(port);` outside the while loop. May the that work

Comment: @Binu please elaborate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following lines of code is trying to create `ServerSocket` again (in fact, infinite number of times) on the port, `5000` and that is why you are getting the error.

```
while (true) {
    try{
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
```

Do it as follows:

```
try{    
    server = new ServerSocket(port);    
}catch(IOException i){    
    System.out.println(i);
}   
while (true) {
    try{
```

Comment: You need a try catch block for the ServerSocket creation

Answer (score 1):

Take Server out of while loop and some more code changes

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {


    //initialize socket and input stream
    private Socket socket = null;
    private ServerSocket server = null;
    private DataInputStream in = null;

    public Server(int port) throws IOException {
        // starts server and waits for a connection
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        while (true) {
            try{

                System.out.println("Server started");
                System.out.println("Waiting for a client ...");
                socket = server.accept();
                System.out.println("Client accepted");
                // takes input from the client socket
                in = new DataInputStream(
                        new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                // reads message from client until "Over" is sent
                while (!line.equals("Over"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        line = in.readUTF();
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    catch(IOException i)
                    {
                        System.out.println(i);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Closing connection");
                // close connection
                socket.close();
                in.close();
            }
            catch(IOException i){
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        new Server(5000);
    }
}
```